# Undefined reference to '_chkstk' using openssl library with C under codeblocks

Tags: c, windows, openssl, mingw, codeblocks

I have downloaded openssl_(x86)_static 1.0.1g binary, copied the lib contenant under "MinGW\lib" and the openssl folder containing the includes files under "MinGW\include".

when i tried to compile the project, using code::blocks 16.01 32bits under windows 7 64bits,
i had this error message

```
||=== Build: Debug in SFI_SMI_Check (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libeay32.lib(tmp32\rand_win.obj):(.text[_readtimer]+0x6)||undefined reference to `_chkstk'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libeay32.lib(tmp32\rand_win.obj):(.text[_readtimer]+0x2f)||undefined reference to `_chkstk'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libeay32.lib(tmp32\rand_win.obj):(.text[_readtimer]+0x4f)||undefined reference to `_chkstk'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libeay32.lib(tmp32\rand_win.obj):(.text[_readscreen]+0xfffffebc)||undefined reference to `_chkstk'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Are you using the 32 bit version of your standard library? Because on X86_64 the naming convention is different. It would be worthwhile to show us the link command. If this is a part of a Makefile, try adding the verbose flag to your compiler flags.

Comment: That `_chkstk` is a MSVC++ specific function, which indicates you're not using OpenSSL libraries specifically built for MinGW, but libraries built by and for the Visual Studio compiler. While such libraries can be used, you don't link with the libraries and object files needed for the VC++ runtime support. Try look for MinGW builds of OpenSSL. The static libraries will then have an ending with `.a` instead of `.lib`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the linker error message shows the `_chkstk` being required in `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libeay32.lib`. Seems to be a part of MinGW only. I could be wrong.

Comment: The `.lib` extension of `libeay32.lib` is a clear indication it was not built by MinGW for MinGW. Static libraries for GCC have an `.a` extension, like `libeay32.a` instead. I also recommend you actually *search* for `_chkstk` and you will find hits only related to VC++.

Comment: I think Someprogrammerdude is correct. If you are using the MSVC compiler, then the switch of interest is `/GS`. If you are using GCC compiler, then the flags of interest are `-fstack-protector` or `-fstack-protector-all`. They mostly do the same thing in about the same way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I checked the symbol table of one of the libraries in my MinGW lib folder. It imported `__chkstk_ms`. So you must be right. This is a wrong toolset issue.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your replies.